# Django: Как сделать особую обработку некоторых полей формы?

Tags: python, django

Имеется модель:

```
class Site(models.Model):
  url = models.URLField(unique=True)
```

Форма для этой модели:

```
class SiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Site
    fields = ['url']
```

Нужно сделать особую обработку для тех случаев, когда url не уникальный. Как это можно сделать?

**UPD**

Eсть еще одна модель:

`class SiteInGroup(models.Model): 
   group = models.ForeignKey("Group") 
   site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name="site_in_group") 
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

Я хочу сделать так: если url не существует, тогда создать объект Site и SiteInGrouip, если же существует, то просто создать SiteInGroup, не трогая Site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто в форму добавить собственный метод `clean_url`, который будет проверять, есть ли в базе уже такой URL или нет:

```
class SiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ['url']

    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        if Site.objects.filter(url=url).exists():
            # тут вы например можете что-то сделать, ну или выбросить исключение
            raise forms.ValidationError("Такой URL уже существует")
        return url
```

[Документация](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/forms/validation.html#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) по валидации форм на русском.

**UPD**

Например можно таким образом обработать в вьюхе, то есть переписать метод `form_valid`:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class SiteCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Site
    form_class = forms.SiteForm
    …
    def form_valid(self, form):
        …
        try:
            return super(SiteCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            # и далее ваш код
```

Правда есть проблема: сюда будут попадать все ошибки целостности данных, а не только в случае, если запись с таким полем существует. Можно добавить немного костылей и проверять, соответствует ли текст ошибки заданному (идею почерпнул [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729696/5033855)), но это ОЧЕНЬ плохое решение, так как зависит не только от используемой БД, но и текст могут поменять сами разработчики базы, и тогда все внезапно перестанет работать.

**UDP 2**

Так как наконец-то мы выяснили исходную задачу, предложу другой метод ее решения:

```
class SiteInGroupCreateView(CreateView):
    model = SiteInGroup
    …
    def form_valid(self, form):
        site, created = Site.objects.get_or_create(url=form.instance.url, …)
        form.instance.site = site
        form.save()
        return super(SiteInGroupCreaateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Что тут происходит: при создании объекта `SiteInGroup` мы, используя метод [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), или возвращаем существующий, или создаем новый объект `Site`, и присваиваем этот объект полю `site`. В целом вот это правильное решение, так как не требует костылей.

Comment: Спасибо. А как сделать, чтобы форма не выдавала ошибку, а успешно выполнилась, не смотря на то, что такой URL уже существует?

Comment: @ИльданКиамов а что она должна делать в таком случае?

Comment: Ничего, просто "сделать вид", что все в порядке. Я потом это во view обрабатываю

Comment: Проблема в том, что форма выдает ошибку "Site with this Url already exists.". Т.е. пользователь подумает, что данные не отправились, хотя на самом деле там все обработалось. Вот нужно сделать так, чтобы форма не выводила эту ошибку

Comment: @ИльданКиамов тогда вопрос: а что вы вообще хотите сделать? чтобы даже при вводе повторяющегося URL сохранялись данные?

Comment: Да, есть еще одна модель:
`class SiteInGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey("Group")
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name="site_in_group")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
`

Я хочу сделать так: если url не существует, тогда создать объект Site и SiteInGrouip, если же существует, то просто создать SiteInGroup, не трогая Site.

Comment: @ИльданКиамов обновил ответ, исходя из постановки задачи